# chrome extensions: How to send a message to the newly created tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to send some data to the newly created tab. I found some answers here to implement the listener first and then send a message. My event listener isn't working and can't catch the message.

manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Cool Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["tabs", 
      "http://*/*", 
      "https://*/*",
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      }
  }
```

background:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab)=>{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        if(tabs.length === 1 ){
            chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://www.youtube.com/", active: true}, (tab)=>{
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"content.js"},tab=>{
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"Active Objects": "elo"})
                })
            })

        }
        else{
            alert("wrong page")
        }
    });
  });
```

content:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdate.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse)=>{
      alert("elo")
    }
);
```

Comment: Replace `onUpdate` with `onMessage`

Answer (score -1):

I've finally got it to work. I didn't actually tested it the first time.

In addition to replacing `onUpdate` with `onMessage` in the content script you
might want to add `setTimeout` functions in the background script to delay the executions of
`chrome.tabs.executeScript` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. Otherwise, you might
get (as I have) a `runtime.lastError: The tab was closed`.

And also you should avoid having multiple function callback arguments named
`tab`. Otherwise, they get overriden.

I simplified the background script to get it to work. You don't actually need
to query the current tab to create a tab and execute a script inside it. So,
I've simply kept `chrome.tabs.create`.

`background.js`:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (_) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.youtube.com/", active: true}, 
        function (yt_tab) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(yt_tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
                setTimeout(function () {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(yt_tab.id, {"Active Objects":"elo"});
                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
    });

});
```

`content.js`:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
       console.log(request);
    }
);
```